# Watching a property for changes

Tags: python, variables, watch

I need a function similar to `gobject.io_add_watch` but for a variable. For example it needs to watch the variable `stop` initialized to `stop = False` and when stop is changed to `True` it must call a function. I can't have a separate thread watching the variable in a loop with a time.sleep.

Is there such a function or a way to do that ?

Comment: Just having `.stop()` would be a more explanatory and logical way of doing it; "stop" is something you do and it's triggering actions which may be expensive, whereas just setting a variable is generally cheap (I realise that in this use case people should realise what it will do, but the principle holds).  `x.stop()` and `x.start()` is neater than `x.stop = True` and `x.stop = False` or `x.running = False` and `x.running = True` or equivalents.

Comment: Even though I showed how to do it, I agree with you on this one. Certainly the technique has other, better applications. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) in a class:

```
class Stopwatch(object):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self._stop = False
        self.callback = callback

    @property
    def stop(self): return self._stop

    @stop.setter
    def stop(self, value):
        self._stop = value
        if value: self.callback()
```